# How to defind __eq__ func for a custom object which need to compare the the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to implement an `__eq__()` method for an custom class `Vertex`.

However, when I carefully think about the problem, I find it is quite weird.

For example

```
class Vertex():
    def __init__(self,node):
        self.id = node
        self.adjacent = {}
```

However for the adjacent `dict`, it store the data like this:

```
 {neighbour_vertex1 : edge, neighbour_vertex2 : edge, ....}
```

If I want to implement the `__eq__()` method, it should look like:

```
def __eq__(self,other):
    return self.id == other and self.adjacent == other.adjacent
```

but the `self.adjacent == other.adjacent` requires to compare the dicts

```
 {neighbour_vertex1 : edge, neighbour_vertex2 : edge, ....}
 {neighbour_vertex1 : edge, neighbour_vertex2 : edge, ....}
```

In order to compare them, I have to define the comparison function for `neighbout_vertex` which indeed is an instance of class `Vertex`.

I think it is like a **chicken or egg question**, any suggestion is appreciated.

**Edit: example**

```
 class Vertex(object):
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        self.adjacent ={}

    def add_vertex(self,obj):
        self.adjacent.update(obj)

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.id == other.id and self.adjacent == other.adjacent

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(id(self))


obj1 = Vertex("one")
obj2 = Vertex("two")
temp = {obj2:"connect 1-2"}
obj1.add_vertex(temp)

obj1s = Vertex("one")
obj2s = Vertex("two")
temp2 = {obj2s:"connect 1-2"}
obj1s.add_vertex(temp2)

if obj1 == obj1s:
    print("True")

else:
    print("False")
```

I came out with a simple example, first I do not want to modify the **hash** function, how can I modify the **__eq__**function to make the above code output
`True` instead of `False`

Comment: So if you implement the `__eq__` method like that, what's the problem?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I just want to compare if two vertices are equal

Comment: I get that. But I don't see the problem with your `__eq__` implementation.

Comment: @Billy what kind of data contains the attribute `Vertex.id`? Isn't it enough to just compare the two `id` attributes of objects?

Comment: @Aran-Fey. Infinite loops/stack overflow seem to be a potential outcome.

Comment: @Ralf I think the id itself is not enough.

Comment: Side note: avoid using the identifier `id`, as it shadows the built in `id` function. Call this the "name" of the vertex, perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need an `__eq__` override here at all. With the design you've chosen, it doesn't make sense for two different instances of `Vertex` to represent "the same vertex", and two `Vertex` instances should only compare equal if they are actually the same object. The default `__eq__` implementation already gives you that behavior.

If you do want different instances of `Vertex` to compare equal, then you need to think about your design first. For example, your definition of `__hash__` as `hash(id(self))` only makes sense if equality works by identity, so your `__hash__` will need to be changed. You'll also need to think about things like, what if vertices `a` and `b` both have `self.id = 1` and `self.adjacent = {c: 'asdf'}`, but `c` has `self.adjacent = {b: 'asdf'}`? Are `a` and `b` equal? You're going to have to come up with a precise definition of the concept of equality you want to use.

One possible redesign would be to move adjacency tracking out of the vertex objects. If vertex objects only have `self.id`, and edges are tracked externally by some sort of Graph object, then it could make sense to compare Vertex objects "by value". At that point, it might make more sense to eliminate the Vertex class entirely, though.

Comment: So, you are saying if I want to compare two object by their value, it would be better to write an external function instead of overriding the __eq__() method?

Comment: @Billy: No, I'm saying that a "by value" comparison doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 2):

@Ralf suggested comparing only the `id` attribute. This is probably the best solution, and you should absolutely go with that if possible.

If not, what is the structure of your vertices? Is it like a tree where adjacency only goes one way? Then writing it like that is fine; eventually you'll run out of nodes.

If the vertices can loop back, we'll have to do something more complicated. The basic trick is to maintain a stack of vertices you haven't visited, and a list of nodes you've already compared. With each loop, pop the top element off the stack. If you see anything that would make the elements compare false, you can return. Otherwise, put the adjacent nodes on the stack if you haven't visited them before, update the visited nodes, and keep going.

(I won't be making the effort to provide a code sample.)